# like or recommend button doesnt work

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

facebook social plugin like / recommend button not working for my site[[www.devilsan.com]](http://www.devilsan.com), it was working before for me and i had 12 recommendations, I was trying to implement the subscribe button to be renderred once someone click the recommend button, but now i have ended up with the recommend button not working,

also I have explicitly defined og meta tags but still they seems to be not working correctly.
[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.devilsan.com](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.devilsan.com)

Please help

Answer (score 0):

According to the linter, you have more than one og tag specified, which is an error condition that must be fixed.  When I look at viewsource, you have more than one specified.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.devilsan.com/">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.devilsan.com">
```

Just remove one of them, and you'll be all set

And yes, I can see that your site has 12 likes
http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.devilsan.com